# Correct way to do an error handling in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

I am considering how to handle this `begin rescue` or error handling in Rails.

I refactor this and put it in a single `begin rescue` but I don't know if it's enough?

```
def generate_shipping


    packages = []

    packages <<  ActiveShipping::Package.new(20,         
                                  [15, 10, 4.5],     # 15x10x4.5 inches Height x Width x Length
                                  units: :imperial)  # not grams, not centimetres


    # FIXME: after error should redirect to workflows
    begin
      order = Spree::Workorder.find(params[:workorder_id]).order

      buyer_information = order.ship_address

    rescue StandardError => e
      flash[:error] = "Record Not Found"
      redirect_to(admin_workorder_product_worksteps_path)
    end




    origin = ActiveShipping::Location.new(country:'US',
                                          state: 'CA',
                                          city: 'Torrance',
                                          zip: '90501',
                                          phone: '424-558-8726',
                                          address1: '357 Van Ness Way #250',
                                          name: 'dentca-test')

    destination = ActiveShipping::Location.new(country: buyer_information.country.iso,
                                                state: buyer_information.state.abbr,
                                                city: buyer_information.city,
                                                zip: buyer_information.zipcode,
                                                phone: buyer_information.phone,
                                                address1: buyer_information.address1,
                                                address2: buyer_information.address2,
                                                name: "#{buyer_information.firstname} #{buyer_information.lastname}")

    # this service type should be dynamic and data will be comming from order.shipments.first.shipping_method
    # per product will have a different shippment
    options = {
      # service_type: 'FEDEX GROUND'
      service_type: params[:shipping_method]
    }

    begin
      shipment_data_response = @fedex.create_shipment(origin, destination, packages, options)

      fedex_rates = @fedex.find_rates(origin, destination, packages)

      blob_img = shipment_data_response.params["ProcessShipmentReply"]["CompletedShipmentDetail"]["CompletedPackageDetails"]["Label"]["Parts"]["Image"]
      tracking_number = shipment_data_response.params["ProcessShipmentReply"]["CompletedShipmentDetail"]["CompletedPackageDetails"]["TrackingIds"]["TrackingNumber"]

      # img = "base64encodedstring"
      image = Magick::Image.from_blob(Base64.decode64(blob_img))
      path = "./shipping_label/#{tracking_number}.png"
      image[0].write(path)

      # json format
      # render json: {rates: fedex_rates, fedex: @fedex.methods, details:shipment_data_response.params, trackingNum:tracking_number}

      # render html img with blob file
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render html:"<img src=data:image/png;base64,#{blob_img}>".html_safe}
      end

    rescue StandardError => e
      flash[:error] = e
      redirect_to admin_workorder_path(params[:workorder_id])
    end


  end
```

So the first begin rescue will not catch any error I don't know why and at the end of rescue I added a `return` so it won't run/invoke the `Active::Shipping`.

Comment: Neither the rescue clause nor the `redirect_to` will return from the method. If you want to return, you need to put that in there explicitly.

Comment: @WaltJones hello sir. You mean add `return` right? yea I added it on the rescue block? is this enough?

Comment: If I understand your intent, yes that should be correct.

Comment: @WaltJones yea I added that on the very last line of my rescue block. but i refactored it to use one try catch so I think i wont need it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`redirect_to admin_workorder_product_worksteps_path` just sets the redirect path for return when the action will finish executing but you probably want the action to redirect and return immediately which should be like:

```
  redirect_to admin_workorder_product_worksteps_path and return
```